# remove white space from table png

Tags: r

I am using the following code to export some tables as pictures. Using the code below can export the table but there is a lot of white space around it which I want to remove. Also is there a way to autosize the images as tables have varying rows?

```
png("picture.png",  width = 650, height = 600, bg = "transparent")
grid.table(df)
dev.off()
```

Expected output will remove the white space that comes around the table and the actual picture should fit the size of the table only

Comment: When you have a problem with particular code on particular objects, it is _your_ responsibility to offer a [MCVE].

Comment: If you cannot fix the plot-generation process (preferred), you can use [`magick`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/index.html)'s [`image_trim`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/vignettes/intro.html#cut_and_edit).